# Refresh Data in ViewModel when Navigating back - Android(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**I have the following setup.**

I have a screen with a list of items (PlantsScreen). When clicking on an item from the list I will be navigated to another screen (AddEditPlantScreen). After editing and saving the item and navigating back to the listScreen, I want to show the updated list of items. But the list is not displaying the updated list but the list before the edit of the item.

In order to have a single source of truth, I am fetching the data from a **node.js** Back-End and then saving it to the local repository (Room). I think I need to refresh the state in the ViewModel to **fetch** the updated list from my repository.

I know I can use a **Job** to do this, but it throws me an error. Is this the correct approach when returning a Flow?

`If yes, how can I achieve this.`
`If not, what alternative approach do I have?`

**plantsListViewModel.kt**

```
private val _state = mutableStateOf<PlantsState>(PlantsState())
val state: State<PlantsState> = _state

init {
  getPlants(true, "")
}
private fun getPlants(fetchFromBackend: Boolean, query: String) {
  viewModelScope.launch {
    plantRepository.getPlants(fetchFromBackend, query)
      .collect { result ->
        when (result) {
          is Resource.Success -> {
            result.data?.let { plants ->
              _state.value = state.value.copy(
                plants = plants,
              )
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

**Here is my repository where I fetch the items in the list from.**

```
// plantsRepository.kt
override suspend fun getPlants(
  fetchFromBackend: Boolean,
  query: String
): Flow<Resource<List<Plant>>> {
  return flow {
    emit(Resource.Loading(true))
    val localPlants = dao.searchPlants(query)
    emit(
      Resource.Success(
        data = localPlants.map { it.toPlant() },
      )
    )
    val isDbEmpty = localPlants.isEmpty() && query.isBlank()
    val shouldLoadFromCache = !isDbEmpty && !fetchFromBackend
    if (shouldLoadFromCache) {
      emit(Resource.Loading(false))
      return@flow
    }
    val response = plantApi.getPlants().plants
    dao.clearPlants()
    dao.insertPlants(
      response.map { it.toPlantEntity() }
    )
    emit(Resource.Success(
      data = dao.searchPlants("").map { it.toPlant() }
    ))
    emit(Resource.Loading(false))
  }
}
```

`The full code for reference can be found here:`
https://gitlab.com/fiehra/plants

## Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Leviathan was able to point me in the right direction i refactored my code by changing the return types of my repository functions, implementing use cases and returning a `Flow<List<Plant>>` instead of `Flow<Resource<List<Plant>>>` for simplicity purposes.

Further removed the suspend marker of the functions in the `PlantDao.kt` and `PlantRepository.kt` as pointed out by Leviathan.

```
// PlantRepositoryImplementation.kt
override fun getPlants(
  fetchFromBackend: Boolean,
  query: String
): Flow<List<Plant>> {
  return flow {
    if (fetchFromBackend) {
      val response = plantApi.getPlants().plants
      dao.clearPlants()
      dao.insertPlants(
        response.map { it.toPlantEntity() }
      )
      val localPlants = dao.searchPlants(query)
      localPlants.collect { plants ->
        emit(plants.map { it.toPlant() })
        return@collect
      }
    } else {
      val localPlants = dao.searchPlants(query)
      localPlants.collect { plants ->
        emit(plants.map { it.toPlant() })
        return@collect
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I started using a Job and GetPlants usecase in my viewModel like this:

```
// PlantsViewModel.kt
private fun getPlants(plantOrder: PlantOrder, fetchFromBackend: Boolean, query: String) {
  getPlantsJob?.cancel()
  getPlantsJob = plantUseCases.getPlants(plantOrder, fetchFromBackend, query)
    .onEach { plants ->
      _state.value = state.value.copy(
        plants = plants,
        plantOrder = plantOrder
      )
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

I also had to remove the suspend in the `PlantDao.kt`

```
// PlantDao.kt
fun searchPlants(query: String): Flow<List<PlantEntity>>
```

This is the code for my GetPlants usecase:

```
// GetPlantsUsecase.kt
class GetPlants
  (
  private val repository: PlantRepository,
) {
  operator fun invoke(
    plantOrder: PlantOrder = PlantOrder.Name(OrderType.Descending),
    fetchFromBackend: Boolean,
    query: String
  ): Flow<List<Plant>> {
    return repository.getPlants(fetchFromBackend, query).map { plants ->
      when (plantOrder.orderType) {
        is OrderType.Ascending -> {
          // logic for sorting
          }
        }
        is OrderType.Descending -> {
          // logic for sorting
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually have two sources of truth: One is the room database, the other the `_state` object in the view model.

To reduce this to a single source of truth you need to move the collection of the flow to the compose function where the data is needed. You will do this using the extension function `StateFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` from the artifact `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose`. This will automatically subscribe and unsubscribe the flow when your composable enters and leaves the composition.

Since you want the business logic to stay in the view model you have to apply it before the flow is collected. The idea is to only *transform* the flow in the view model:

```
class PlantsViewModel {
    private var fetchFromBackend: Boolean by mutableStateOf(true)
    private var query: String by mutableStateOf("")

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    val state: StateFlow<PlantsState> =
        snapshotFlow { fetchFromBackend to query }
            .flatMapLatest { plantRepository.getPlants(it.first, it.second) }
            .mapLatest(PlantsState::of)
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
                initialValue = PlantsState.Loading,
            )
            
    // ...
}
```

If you want other values for `fetchFromBackend` and `query` you just need to update the variables; the flow will automatically recalculate the state object. It can be as simple as just calling something like this:

```
fun requestPlant(fetchFromBackend: Boolean, query: String) {
    this.fetchFromBackend = fetchFromBackend
    this.query = query
}
```

The logic to create a `PlantsState` from a result can then be done somewhere else in the view model. Replace your `PlantsViewModel.getPlants()` with this and place it at file level outside of the PlantsViewModel class:

```
private fun PlantsState.Companion.of(result: Resource<List<Plant>>): PlantsState = when (result) {
    is Resource.Success -> {
        result.data?.let { plants ->
            PlantsState.Success(
                plants = plants,
            )
        } ?: TODO("handle case where result.data is null")
    }
    is Resource.Error -> {
        PlantsState.Error("an error occurred")
    }
    is Resource.Loading -> {
        PlantsState.Loading
    }
}
```

With the `PlantsState` class replaced by this:

```
sealed interface PlantsState {
    object Loading : PlantsState

    data class Success(
        val plants: List<Plant> = emptyList(),
        val plantOrder: PlantOrder = PlantOrder.Name(OrderType.Descending),
        val isOrderSectionVisible: Boolean = false,
    ) : PlantsState

    data class Error(
        val error: String,
    ) : PlantsState

    companion object
}
```

Then, wherever you need the state (in PlantsScreen f.e.), you can get a state object with

```
val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

Thanks to kotlin flows `state` will always contain the most current data from the room database, and thanks to the compose magic your composables will always update when anything in the `state` object updates, so that you really only have one single source of truth.

Additionally:

- `PlantRepository.getPlants()` should not be marked as a suspend function because it just creates a flow and won't block; long running data retrieval will be done in the collector.
- You will need to manually import `androidx.compose.runtime.getValue` and the `androidx.compose.runtime.setValue` for some of the delegates to work.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, i refactored my code quite a bit as your answer pointed me in the right direction. marking it as a suspend function was wrong and i probly did it because android studio told me to do so without completely understanding.